# How to initialize a variable, but once done, its value is final

Tags: swift

I have a model object variable in Swift View Controller. The thing I'd like to do is that at initialisation of the VC, i don't have a value for it. But after an async network call I have the parsed model object which is what this variable should hold, but from then on I don't want anything to change the value of the model variable.

Is it possible to do so in Swift? if yes, how?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Based on Babul Prabhakar answer, but a bit more clean.

**Approach 1:**

```
var test: String? { didSet { test = oldValue ?? test } }

test = "Initial string"
test = "Some other string"
test = "Lets try one last time"

print(test) // "Initial string"
```

Edit: made it shorter

**Approach 2:**

```
let value: String
value = "Initial string"
```

I guess the second approach is the "built-in" option of Swift to declare a variable once. This is only possible when the variable is assigned right after the declaration though.

Comment: I like this approach better, in @Babul Prabhakar's approach if **myPrivateVar** was set to nil the setter could still write. This approach guarantees that will never happen. +1

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the cleanest and shortest approach.

Comment: I don't think the first approach works in a class or struct since it will be initialized to nil automatically. Just a heads up.

Answer (score 9):

What you can do is

```
private var myPrivateVar:String?;

var publicGetter:String {
    set {
        if myPrivateVar == nil {
            myPrivateVar = newValue;

        }

    }
    get {
        return myPrivateVar!;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd personally go with @Eendje or @Babul Prabhakar's approach if `myPrivateVar` was somehow set to `nil` the setter *could* still write twice. I wanted to share another option that is `guaranteed` to never get set twice (*as long as the token is never written to!*):

```
    private var token: dispatch_once_t = 0

    private var setOnce : String?

    var publicGetter: String {

        set (newValue) {
            dispatch_once(&token) {
                self.setOnce = newValue
            }
        }

        get {
            guard let setOnce = setOnce else {
                return ""
            }
            return setOnce
        }
    }
```

> The dispatch_once() function provides a simple and efficient mechanism
>   to run an initializer exactly
>        once, similar to pthread_once(3).  Well designed code hides the use of lazy initialization.  For exam-ple: example:

[source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_once.3.html)

Answer (score 1):

Swift support lazy variables.
For example the following variable will be set to the value "Hi There!" only when accessed.

```swift
// variable declaration, not yet initialized
lazy var myString = "Hi There!"


// myString gets initialized here since value is been accessed.
var someOtherVariable = myString
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no *traditional way* in Swift, and either in another languages too. (Traditional way here means you use supported language keyword for your purpose). It's difficult for you to know this variable has been initialized before (without using some state variable for checking).

You can use this design pattern: declare all properties as `private` (so you **can't** set those properties somewhere else in your code). And you will initialize all properties in `constructor`. So all properties will be initialized only one.

`Objective-C` and `Swift 2` has access modifier such as `public` `protected` `private`.

**note**: `Swift 1` doesn't have access modifier.

Here is demo in `Swift 2`:

```
class ViewModel {
    private var firstName : String;
    private var lastName : String;

    init (firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
}
```

Here is demo in `Objective-C`:

```
@interface ViewModel : NSObject
    {
        @private
        NSString *firstName;   
        @private
        NSString *lastName;
    }      
    - (id)initWithFirstName:(NSString *)_firstName
                   lastName:(NSString *)_lastName       
    @end

    @implementation ViewModel     
    - (id)initWithFirstName:(NSString *)_firstName
                   lastName:(NSString *)_lastName
    {
        if( self = [super init] )
        {
            firstName = _firstName;
            lastName = _lastName;
        }       
        return self;
    }        
    @end
```

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

The top answer involving didSet is error prone - a caller may try to set the variable and won't be notified that the new value is ignored, which can lead to all sorts of hard to fix bugs later on.

Assuming you want the value to be non-nil:

```
var test: String! {
    willSet(newTest) {
        guard test == nil, newTest != nil else { fatalError("value was already set") }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Swift 5, you can use Property Wrapper

```swift
@propertyWrapper
public struct InitOnce<Value> {
    var storage: Value?
    
    public init() {
        self.storage = nil
    }
    
    public var wrappedValue: Value {
        get {
            guard let storage = storage else {
                fatalError("Attempt to access the instance before setting it.")
            }
            return storage
        }
        set {
            if storage == nil {
                storage = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```swift
@InitOnce var sentence: String

print(sentence) // -> fatalError("Attempt to access the instance before setting it.")
sentence = "Hello, world!"
print(sentence) // Hello, world!
sentence = "Thanks"
print(sentence) // Hello, world!
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of these answers just work if your variable is optional.

This is a method that works for all kinds of variables including for variables inside functions.

```
// run code once inside function
struct Run { static var Once : Bool = false }

if Run.Once == false {
  Run.Once = true
  // do something here
}
```